# Как задать формат для строки

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Как задать формат для строки?

К примеру, есть строка длинной в 4 символа. Имеет формат: БЦБЦ
Где: Б - буква, Ц - цифра

Comment: Понятие, в принципе не существующее. Можно проверить на соответствие шаблону и вывести только соответствующие ему.

Comment: И как это реализовать?

Comment: Что именно - это? пока вопрос совершенно невменяем.

Comment: "проверить на соответствие шаблону и вывести только соответствующие ему"